# Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextView not opening keyboard after back press

Tags: android, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I'm building an Android application with Jetpack Compose and the latest version (at the time) of material3 components.

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta01")
```

Everything works nicely but for some reason, the `OutlinedTextView` only opens the keyboard when getting focus for the first time. If I close the keyboard by using the back button it won't reopen when tapping the `OutlinedTextView` again.

Has somebody seen this issue before? If so, what's the way to fix it?

The code for the view is the following

```
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
        label = {
            Text("Search")
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug with the material3 components library happening from version alpha12.

Rolling back to alpha11 fixes the issue.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317641563

Answer (score 0):

now they have a fix for this just upgrade this lib to latest its something like

implementation ("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-rc01")